# Filter multiple values in Swift

Tags: data-structures, filter, contains, swift5, higher-order-functions

I know that **Filter** and **contains** in Swift are very powerful and it has made many of my works easy. However, I'm stranded in a situation where I have to **filter/verify** a set of different values from an array of Model.

Let's assume I have a model like below

```
 struct Person {
       var name: String
       var ID: String
    }
```

And I have an array of models like below:

```
[
            {
                sku = "123"
                attributes =      [
                    {
                        name:"Victor"
                        ID:"250"
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Shaw"
                        ID:"252"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                sku = "123"
                attributes = [
                    {
                        name:"John"
                        ID:"222"
                    },
                    {
                        name:"Nixon"
                        ID:"333"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Now I would like to filter the **sku** by multiple IDs inside **attributes** . For example, if I need to filter **skus** which has **ID:250 and ID:252** I need something like this to achieve it.

```
     personModelArray.forEach { person in
        person.attributes.contains(where: { $0.ID == 250 && $0.ID == 252  })
    }

OR

   personModelArray.forEach { person in
        person.attributes.filter { $0.ID == 250 && $0.ID == 252  }
    }
```

What I want is a condition like to to verify that the **attributes** array has both the values.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `$0.ID == 250 && $0.ID == 252` is ALWAYS false! How one storage could have two different values at the same moment?

Look at this simple example

```
struct Item {
    let a: Int
    let b: String
}

let arr = [Item(a: 0, b: "zero"),
           Item(a: 1, b: "one"),
           Item(a: 2, b: "two"),
           Item(a: 4, b: "four")]
```

To filter all items, where a == 1 OR a == 4

```
let arr0 = arr.filter { item in
    item.a == 1 ||
    item.a == 4
}
```

or, if You prefer $ parameter notation

```
let arr1 = arr.filter { $0.a == 1 || $0.a == 4 }
```

eventually,

```
let arr2 = arr.filter { item in
    [1, 4].contains(item.a)
}
let arr3 = arr.filter { [1, 4].contains($0.a) }
```